# jQuery AJAX, conditional not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

My function makes a search by ID and by name, and I'm doing it in MVC. The problem is that it enters the conditional (`if`) and the AJAX is run correctly, but then it also goes to the `else` and runs it too. Apparently my data in the dialog is blank because it send the `alert` window. It sometimes opens the dialog correctly, but when I change the module and come back the `if` and `else` are run again and the blank dialog appears.

What can be happening? When I make the first click, it blocks, I click again and then the data appears...

```
function buscaProducto(url, cod, name) {

    if (cod.length != 0 || name.length != 0) {
        var producto = name;
        var identidad = cod;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            error: AjaxFailure,
            beforeSend: AjaxBegin,
            data: { productoNombre: producto, identidad: identidad },

            success: function (data) {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    bigframe: true,
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: 900,
                    heigth: 700,
                    resizable: false,
                });

                $("#progressbar").hide();
                $("#dialog").html(data);

                console.log("Entregó los datos al #dialog");

            }
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("<p>Debe ingresar una opcion de busqueda</p>", $(window).height() / 3)
        this.abort();
    }
}
```

I think the cache might be stuck

the controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BusquedaProducto(string productoNombre, string identidad)
        {
            if (productoNombre.Equals(""))
            {
                if (identidad.Equals(""))
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    var code = (from p in db.GN_Portafolio
                                where p.CodigoPortafolio.StartsWith(identidad) && p.SenSerial == true
                                select p).ToList();
                    if (code.Equals("0"))
                    {
                        return HttpNotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return View(code);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var producto = (from p in db.GN_Portafolio
                                where p.NombrePortafolio.StartsWith(productoNombre)
                                select p).ToList().Take(100);
                if (producto.Equals("0"))
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    return View(producto);
                }
            }

        }
```

the view

```
@model IEnumerable<SifActivoFijo.Models.GN_Portafolio>

<form class="items">
    <label>items por Pagina: </label>
    <select>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>15</option>
    </select>
</form>
<input name="button" type="button" onclick="$('#dialog').dialog('close');" value="Cerrar" />
<table  class="tablas">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CodigoPortafolio)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NombrePortafolio)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody id="pagina">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodigoPortafolio)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NombrePortafolio)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="seleccion" type="button" value="Seleccionar" />


                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="holder"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('input.seleccion').click(function () {
            var codigo = $(this).parent().prev().prev();
            var nombre = $(this).parent().prev();
            $('#activoFijo_GN_Portafolio_CodigoPortafolio').val($.trim(codigo.text()));
            $('#GN_Portafolio_CodigoPortafolio').val($.trim(codigo.text()));
            $('#nombrePortafolio').val($.trim(nombre.text()));
            $("#activoFijo_DescripcionActivoFijo").val($.trim(nombre.text()));
            document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = '<div id="progressbar" class="progressbar" style="display: none;"></div>';
            $("#dialog").dialog('close');
        });
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand you question. Maybe you can write it in Spanish and I will help you with both the translation and the answer.

Comment: As far as I can see, the code is correct. Is the controller returning the correct data? The error might be there instead.

Comment: arriba publique controlador y vista.. gracias  Arturo Torres Sánchez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using return type as ActionResult in server side method. So this return your entire view, then page will get reload. So this has happening. So please change your methods return type to any other like string, Jsonresult, etc.,

Comment: the function must change something ?? better data with json ?